# Mathematica shows complex roots while asked for reals?

Tags: equation-solving

I ran the following code in Mathematica

```
ToRadicals[Reduce[-14848 c^4 + 38016 c^3 x - 30888 c^2 x^2 + 6480 c x^3 + 1215 x^4 == 0 && c < 0,x,Reals]]
```

This should give the real roots of the polynomial. However, the output displays two complex roots? How is this possible?

Thanks in advance!e

Comment: I'm getting a symbolic result; did you remember to run ``ClearAll["Global`*"]`` before trying that?

Comment: I ran the command. Still get the same answer (see post @rewi). Mathematica displays complex roots?

Comment: Why are you doing ToRadicals? Real expressions involving radicals often involve cancellation of imaginary components, a process that is prone to round-off error if you ask for an approximate numerical result.

Comment: The reason that I do it, is to obtain easier expressions to work with since I need an explicit result for the root. I thought Mathematica could handle these things. If you look at my latest comment (below) then Mathematica does it correct for some polynomials. It is probably due to the reason you mention, however it is quite annoying since I do not know which analytical expression to use while I'm sure there are two real roots.

Comment: `Root[]` **is** an explicit result, with better behavior than a radical expression.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. But Root[] is impractical to work with.

Comment: The `Root` machinery keeps track of which roots are real and which roots are complex, something that `ToRadicals` cannot do reliably. On further experimentation, I see that this is your problem, not simply round-off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting this

```
ToRadicals@
 Reduce[-14848 c^4 + 38016 c^3 x - 30888 c^2 x^2 + 6480 c x^3 + 
     1215 x^4 == 0 && c < 0, x, Reals]
```

[image]

addendum

Interesting, without `ToRadicals` one get only real roots.

```
f = -14848 c^4 + 38016 c^3 x - 30888 c^2 x^2 + 6480 c x^3 + 1215 x^4;
sol = Reduce[f == 0 && c < 0, x, Reals]
```

[image]

```
sol[[2]] /. c -> -1 // N
(* x == -1.12557 || x == 8.69121 *)

Manipulate[
 Plot[-14848 c^4 + 38016 c^3 x - 30888 c^2 x^2 + 6480 c x^3 + 
   1215 x^4, {x, -10, 10}], {c, -10, -0.1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what I got. Those $x$ are complex?

Comment: @user39039 see my addendum

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers!
I know it's not the tradition to answer your own question, but I want to give a more lengthy response (if that is ok). If I'm not mistaken, it seems that Mathematica means that $\mbox{Root}[\ldots,1]$ and $\mbox{Root}[\ldots,2]$ are indeed the real roots, but Mathematica convert it the wrong way when using `ToRadical`? Now, consider another quartic

```
ToRadicals[Reduce[375 c^8 - 3600 c^6 x + 8088 c^4 x^2 - 6912 c^2 x^3 + 2048 x^4 == 0 && c < 0,x,Reals]]
```

Then Mathematica displays the real roots this way. Furthermore, when I select the third root

```
ToRadicals[Root[-14848 c^4 + 38016 c^3 # - 30888 c^2 #^2 + 6480 c #^3 + 1215 #^4 &,3]]
```

then this one is indeed real. The same goes for the fourth root. Right now, this does not make any sense? For some polynomials it does it right and four other it looks like Mathematica invert the order. Strange ...

Comment: Under "Possible issues" in the `ToRadicals`: "The result may not be equal to the Root object for some values of the parameter". Branch cuts are always an adventure in computer algebra.